# Fill a Set of domain objects on JSP page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, navigation

I have a set of Permission and controller, which add to model that set. I need to fill a set with parameters selected by the user.

```
<form:form id="intUserPermissions" method="post" action="/user/new/2" 
    modelAttribute="permissions">
    <c:forEach items="${permissions}" var="permission">
        <p><label for="${permission.name}"></label>
            <b>${permission.name}</b>
            <form:checkbox path="permission.name" id="${permission.name}"/>
        </p>
    </c:forEach>
    <div class="content"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Set"></div>
</form:form>


public String createForm(@ModelAttribute User user,
                             @ModelAttribute HashSet<Permission> permissions,
                             @PathVariable("pageId") Integer pageId,
                             ModelMap model) {

    <...>

    model.addAttribute("permissions", service.getPermissions());

    <...>
}
```

How to fill a set with Permissions for modelAttribute?

Comment: Don't mix spring tag libs and jstl here. Just use jstl.